Problem after updating to geoflutterfire_plus package
I use to have the package geoflutterfire2, I used this package to get the id of users that where in a certain distance from a specific location (latitude and longitude), my code was:
getSuppliersLocation(BuildContext context, int requestReach, String serviceCode,
    double lat, double long) async {
  final serviceRequest = Provider.of<CustomerRequest>(context, listen: false);
  final user = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid;
  final fcmToken = await firebaseMessaging.getToken();

  late Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream;
  late GeoFlutterFire geo;

  geo = GeoFlutterFire();
  final radius = requestReach / 1000;
  String field = 'location';

  String collectionRoute;
  productionStatus
      ? collectionRoute = 'supplier'
      : collectionRoute = 'Testsupplier';

  var collectionReference = firestore
      .collection(collectionRoute)
      .where(serviceCode, isEqualTo: true)
      .where('isActive', isEqualTo: true)
      .where('isVerified', isEqualTo: true);

  GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: lat, longitude: long);

  stream = geo
      .collection(collectionRef: collectionReference)
      .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field, strictMode: true);

  controllerSuppliers = stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
    List<String> ids = [];
    List<String> tokenIds = [];
    List<String> phoneNumbers = [];
    for (var item in documentList) {
      final data = item.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (data.containsKey('id') && data['id'] != user) {
        ids.add(data['id']);
      }
      if (data.containsKey('tokenId') && data['tokenId'] != fcmToken) {
        tokenIds.add(data['tokenId']);
      }
      if (data.containsKey('phoneNumber')) {
        phoneNumbers.add(data['phoneNumber']);
      }
    }

    if (ids.isNotEmpty) {
      serviceRequest.setAuthorizedSuppliersIds = ids;
    } else {}

    serviceRequest.setAuthorizedSuppliersIds = ids;
    serviceRequest.setAuthorizedSuppliersTokenIds = tokenIds;
    serviceRequest.setAuthorizedSuppliersPhoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
  });
}

but I have to update to flutter 3.22, and with that my Google Sign In stop working, so I have to update the firebase_auth and firebase_core to avoid the Google Sign In problem, but when doing that, the geoflutterfire2 stop working, because it depends in an older firebase_auth and firebase_core package, geoflutterfire2 last update was 19 months ago, so I look for a new package and I found the Geoflutterfire_plus package, so I try to update my code but I'm blocked at this problem:
I need to make a query to get only the collection that meet this criteria:
  var collectionReference = firestore
      .collection(collectionRoute)
      .where(serviceCode, isEqualTo: true)
      .where('isActive', isEqualTo: true)
      .where('isVerified', isEqualTo: true);

but the problem is that in order to do the stream:
  Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>> stream =
        GeoCollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>>(collectionReference).subscribeWithin(
            center: center,
            radiusInKm: radius,
            field: field,
            geopointFrom: geopointFrom);

the collectionReference needs to be CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>>, so the error is at this:

please help!!!

Not sure what the problem is, but (since March 2024) you no longer need a Flutter*Fire library to do geoqueries on Firestore. See my article here for how to perform geoqueries without any add-ons: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-perform-geoqueries-on-firestore-somewhat-efficiently-6c2f10fd285f
